# Returning a default value. (C#)

Tags: c#, generics, default-value

I'm creating my own dictionary and I am having trouble implementing the [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132143(VS.85).aspx) function.  When the key isn't found, I don't have anything to assign to the out parameter, so I leave it as is.  This results in the following error:  "The out parameter 'value' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method"

So, basically, I need a way to get the default value (0, false or nullptr depending on type).  My code is similar to the following:

```
class MyEmptyDictionary<K, V> : IDictionary<K, V>
{
    bool IDictionary<K, V>.TryGetValue (K key, out V value)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ....

}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You are looking for the [`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions) keyword.

For example, in the example you gave, you want something like:

```
class MyEmptyDictionary<K, V> : IDictionary<K, V>
{
    bool IDictionary<K, V>.TryGetValue (K key, out V value)
    {
        value = default(V);
        return false;
    }

    ....

}
```

Comment: Just tried to use 'default' and didn't realise I couldn't until I upgraded to C# 7.1.

Comment: @BrettRigby default was made available in C# 2. Running an empty CLI project with default(int) in C#1 (ISO-1 in Visual Studio) gets you this error:
`Program.cs(11,31,11,38): error CS8022: Feature 'default operator' is not available in C# 1. Please use language version 2 or greater.` But using C#2 (ISO-2) or greater works fine.

Comment: @BrettRigby However if you meant the use of `value = default` then you need [C# 7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#default-literal-expressions).

Answer (score 7):

```
default(T)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
return default(int);

return default(bool);

return default(MyObject);
```

so in your case you would write:

```
class MyEmptyDictionary<K, V> : IDictionary<K, V>
{
    bool IDictionary<K, V>.TryGetValue (K key, out V value)
    {
        ... get your value ...
        if (notFound) {
          value = default(V);
          return false;
        }
    }

....
```

}