# default value for generic type in c#

Tags: c#, generics, default-value

The docs for [Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) say:

> When this method returns, [the value argument] contains the value associated with the specified key, if the key is found; otherwise, the **default value for the type of the value parameter**. This parameter is passed uninitialized.

I need to mimic this in my class. *How do I find the default value for type T?*

---

How can this question be modified to make it show up in the search?

Exact duplicate of [Returning a default value. (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367378/returning-a-default-value-c)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
default(T);
```

so:

```
public T Foo<T>(T Bar)
{
   return default(T);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
default(T);
```

Comment: Yep.. introduced along with generics (.NET 2.0, 2005)

Answer (score 9):

Using the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(VS.80).aspx) keyword:

```
T t = default(T)
```