# How can I get the default value of a type in a non-generic way?

Tags: c#, default-value

I know the "default" keyword returns the default value of a statically determined type, as shown for instance in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367378/returning-a-default-value-c).

However, given an instance of a type, is there a simple way to get the default value of this type, dynamically ?
The only way I found while googling is [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2006/05/21/Non_2D00_generic-default-values-in-C_23003F00_-Why-not_3F002100_.aspx) :

```
static object DefaultValue(Type myType)
{
    if (!myType.IsValueType)
        return null;
    else
        return Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
}
```

But I'd like to avoid the Activator class if possible.

Comment: Welcome to expression world? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582259/fast-creation-of-objects-instead-of-activator-createinstancetype :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely your best route.

I wouldn't be afraid of using the Activator class here.  This is a pretty standard class that is depended on by the compilers.  For instance this VB code

```
Public Sub Example(Of T as New)()
  Dim x = new T()
End Sub
```

Translates into roughly this code

```
Public Sub Example(Of T As New)()
  Dim x = Activator.CreateInstance(OF T)
ENd Sub
```

Comment: That is generics (which the OP wants to avoid), and isn't the same as "default" - it should return null for classes.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I know Reflection is uber-powerfull, but I'm reluctant to use it when there are simple solutions. But if there's no choice, let's go with it :)

Comment: @Marc, very true, I was mainly trying to give an example showing that Activator is not an *evil* class

Comment: I quite agree - simply that it doesn't seem to answer the original question... Oh well, the OP is happy, at least... ;-p

Answer (score 7):

Why do you want to avoid Activator? Basically that *is* the way of doing it.

I mean, you could write a generic method and then call that via reflection, but that's a pretty hideous "long cut" just to avoid Activator.