# Generic method to instantiate a variable of any type (including nullable struct)?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, nullable

Let's say I have this function which *instantiates a `new` variable with **default/empty value** for any type*

```
public static T GetDefault<T>() where T : new() //body of this method is the question
{
    T t = new T();
    return t;
}
```

The problem with the above function is when I have something like `int?` for `T`. Because if I have

```
int? t = new int?();
```

`t` will be null! I do not want this to happen, instead I want the default value of `int` to be returned which is `0`.

To solve this, I can have different overloads of `GetDefault` function for `int?`, `bool?` etc but that's not elegant. I can also check internally in the function if type is `int?` or `bool?` etc, but how would I go about instantiating it's base type?

Or the question boils down to how to identify if `T` is nullable struct and accordingly how to instantiate the nullable struct..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a nullable object via Activator.CreateInstance returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691601/creating-a-nullable-object-via-activator-createinstance-returns-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Type realType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
t = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(realType ?? typeof(T));
```

Comment: Nice solution! Except that `new T()` would be marginally faster for structs. Doesn't matter, this looks elegant :)

Comment: @nawfal: Actually, I'm pretty sure that's false.  `new T()` compiles to `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`, which in turn calls `rt.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(...)`.  `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)` calls a very similar overload.  _Disclaimer: I haven't measured it_.

Comment: I did tell it was only for structs. new T() performs better. But for nullable types, its all the same..

Comment: May be `CreateInstance` for structs were slower since it involved unboxing when cast to `int`. Have a look at related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069661/does-system-activator-createinstancet-have-performance-issues-big-enough-to-di