# How to create a new instance of an object by dynamic lambda and IL?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, expression, il

I know that `Activator.CreateInstance()` can create a new instance of an `object`. But I'm searching for a way to create an instance by `IL` and `Expression`. I think I can create a dynamic lambda to create an instance of a type, and cache the lambda to speed up objects initialization. Am I right? Can you help me please?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788813/best-way-to-create-an-instance-of-run-time-determined-type/9789971#9789971

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can represent creation of an object using [`Expression.New()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351456.aspx). You can pass to it either a `Type` that has parameterless constructor, or a `ConstructorInfo`, along with `Expression`s representing the constructor parameters. If you want to return an `object` and you want it to work for value types too, you also need to add an `Expression.Convert()`.

Putting it all together, the equivalent to `Activator.CreateInstance()` could look like this:

```
object CreateInstance(Type type)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(
        Expression.Convert(Expression.New(type), typeof(object)))
        .Compile()();
}
```

If you want to do the same in IL, you need to use [the `newobj` instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj.aspx) for reference types. If you want to do the same for values types, you can create a local variable of that type, box it and return it:

```
object CreateInstance(Type type)
{
    var method = new DynamicMethod("", typeof(object), Type.EmptyTypes);
    var il = method.GetILGenerator();

    if (type.IsValueType)
    {
        var local = il.DeclareLocal(type);
        // method.InitLocals == true, so we don't have to use initobj here
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, local);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, type);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }
    else
    {
        var ctor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }

    return method.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I understand it. So if the constractor has some arguments, how can I provide theme? Another Q is that where can I learn about `Expression`? Where did you learn it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Everything you need to know about various .Net types is [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx), including [the documentation for `Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356138.aspx). And like I said, you can provide parameters to the constructor as parameters to the `New()` method, probably using `Expression.Constant()`.