# How to convert Type to TEnum in C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have a `EnumSearchExpressionProvider<TEnum>` class. I need to assign an instance of this class inside attribute called `SearchableEnumAttribute`.

Here is my `EnumSearchExpressionProvider<TEnum>`,

```cs
public class EnumSearchExpressionProvider<TEnum> : StringSearchExpressionProvider where TEnum : struct
{
    public override ConstantExpression GetValue(string input)
    {
        if (!Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(input.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty), true, out var value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid search value.");
        }

        return Expression.Constant(value);
    }
}
```

Here is my `SearchableEnumAttribute` class,

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SearchableEnumAttribute : SearchableAttribute
{
    public SearchableEnumAttribute(Type enumType)
    {
        ExpressionProvider = new EnumSearchExpressionProvider<enumType>();
    }
}
```

In my model, I'm using this attribute to one of the property as,

```cs
[SearchableEnum(typeof(Position))]
public string Position { get; set; }
```

here is my `Position` Enum,

```cs
public enum Position
{
    [Display(Name = "Accountant")]
    Accountant,
    [Display(Name = "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)")]
    ChiefExecutiveOfficer,
}
```

However I'm getting compile error in this line in my `SearchableEnumAttribute` constructor,

```cs
ExpressionProvider = new EnumSearchExpressionProvider<enumType>();
```

How to convert `Type` to `TEnum`? Am I doing something impossible or wrong? Is there any better way to do this? Please assist me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like:

```cs
ExpressionProvider = (StringSearchExpressionProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(
    typeof(EnumSearchExpressionProvider<>).MakeGenericType(enumType));
```

?

Comment: Should be noted that this is not suited for "heavy usage" as `Activator.CreateInstance` takes "ages" compared with some other possibilities https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582259/fast-creation-of-objects-instead-of-activator-createinstancetype/6882881 (and that rather then using this, the API may should be improved)

Comment: @X39 So is it possible to make this better?

Comment: @fingers10 the usual trick is to cache your strategy per type, so that you don't need to keep doing it