# How to remove duplicates in List of Class with Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq, duplicates

I have a list of class :

```
class GroupAssets
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> Assets { get; set; }
    }

        List<GroupAssets> GroupList2 = new List<GroupAssets>{
                new GroupAssets { Name="Group1", Assets = new List<string>{ "A","B","C","D" }},
                new GroupAssets { Name="Group1", Assets = new List<string>{ "A","B","E","F" }},
                new GroupAssets { Name="Group3", Assets = new List<string>{ "A","B","H","G" }},
                new GroupAssets { Name="Group4", Assets = new List<string>{ "A","I","C","J" }}
    };
```

I would like to remove the duplicates and have this result :

```
Group1 => D
Group2 => E,F
Group3 => H,G
Group4 => I,J
Duplicate => A,B,C
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: so i suppose your list is new List<string>{ "A","B","C","D" }? and you have group2 instead group1?  could you fix your errors please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have
class GroupAssets
{
public String Name { get; set; }
public IList Assets { get; set; }
}

```
List<GroupAssets> GroupList = new List<GroupAssets>{
  new GroupAssets { Name="Group1", Assets = new List<string>{ "A" ,"B", "C", "D" }},
  new GroupAssets { Name="Group2", Assets = new List<string>{ "A" ,"B", "E", "F" }},
  new GroupAssets { Name="Group3", Assets = new List<string>{ "A" ,"B", "H", "G" }},
  new GroupAssets { Name="Group4", Assets = new List<string>{ "A" ,"I", "C", "J" }},
};
```

note, that each `Asset` has **4** items (not **1**) you can put

**Code:**

```
HashSet<string> duplicates = new HashSet<string>();
HashSet<string> all = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var item in GroupList)
  foreach (var asset in item.Assets) 
    if (!all.Add(asset))     // duplicate if all contains the asset
      duplicates.Add(asset);

// removing duplicates from each Asset
foreach (var item in GroupList)
  item.Assets.RemoveAll(item => duplicates.Contains(item));
```

**Let's have a look:**

```
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GroupList
  .Select(item => $"{item.Name} => {string.Join(", ", item.Assets)}"));

Console.WriteLine(report);

Console.WriteLine("Duplicate => {string.Join(", ", duplicates)}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
Group1 => D
Group2 => E, F
Group3 => H, G
Group4 => I, J
Duplicate => A, B, C
```

If, however, each of `Assets` contains 1 comma separated item, you should add `Split` and `Join`:

```
HashSet<string> duplicates = new HashSet<string>();
HashSet<string> all = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var item in GroupList)
  foreach (var asset in item.Assets.SelectMany(list => list.Split(','))) 
    if (!all.Add(asset)) 
      duplicates.Add(asset);

foreach (var item in GroupList) {
  item.Assets = item
    .Assets
    .Select(asset => asset.Split(',').Where(c => !duplicates.Contains(c)))
    .Where(asset => asset.Any())
    .Select(asset => string.Join(",", asset))
    .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         List<GroupAssets> GroupList = new List<GroupAssets>{ 
                    new GroupAssets { Name="Group1", Assets = new List<string>{ "A","B","C","D" }},
                    new GroupAssets { Name="Group1", Assets = new List<string>{ "A","B","E","F" }},
                    new GroupAssets { Name="Group3", Assets = new List<string>{ "A","B","H","G" }},
                    new GroupAssets { Name="Group4", Assets = new List<string>{ "A","I","C","J" }}
        };
    var assetList = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    foreach (var g in GroupList.Select(x=> x.Assets)) {
         g.ForEach(x=> {
             if (!assetList.ContainsKey(x)) assetList.Add(x,1);
             else assetList[x]++;
         });
    }

    var nonUnique = assetList.Where(x=> x.Value > 1).Select(x=> x.Key).ToList();
    nonUnique.ForEach(x=> { Console.WriteLine(x); });
```

alternative solution in case you want to know the total amount of duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I assume you made a mistake and property `GroupAssets.Assets` contains the list of assets (`new List<string>() {"A", "B"}`) and not the list of comma separated strings with only one string in the list (`new List<string>() {"A,B"}`).

First you have to figure out what are the duplicates. You could group items by one of strings "A" to "J" and the value `int` is the number of occurrences of that key in all lists. We take code from [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/687347/395718), enhanced with one `SelectMany` because we want to flatten many lists into one.

```
    var assetCount = GroupList
        .SelectMany(x => x.Assets)
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Select(s => new { Asset = s.Key, Count = s.Count() });
```

Then we make list of duplicates, and a list of groups with unique assets:

```
    var duplicates = assetCount.Where(x => x.Count > 1).Select(x => x.Asset).ToList();
    
    var uniqueAssetsGroupList = GroupList
        .Select(x => new GroupAssets() { Name = x.Name, Assets = x.Assets.Except(duplicates).ToList() });
    
    foreach (var group in uniqueAssetsGroupList)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} => {1}", group.Name, string.Join(",", group.Assets)));

    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate => {0}", string.Join(",", duplicates));
```

Comment: Hi Dialecticus, It works! Great, thank you!
Yes sorry, I made a mistake on the list of assets 
I corrected my post.
Thanks again for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

find the unique duplicates and then use except to remove the duplicates from the asset list

```
  [Fact]
        public void TestRemoveDuplicate()
        {
            List<GroupAssets> GroupList = new List<GroupAssets>{
            new GroupAssets { Name="Group1", Assets = new List<string>{ "A" ,"B", "C", "D" }},
            new GroupAssets { Name="Group2", Assets = new List<string>{ "A" ,"B", "E", "F" }},
            new GroupAssets { Name="Group3", Assets = new List<string>{ "A" ,"B", "H", "G" }},
            new GroupAssets { Name="Group4", Assets = new List<string>{ "A" ,"I", "C", "J" }},
            };
            IList<String> duplicates = new List<String>();
            foreach (var item in GroupList)
            {
                foreach (var element in item.Assets)
                {
                    if (GroupList.Where(e =>e.Name!=item.Name && e.Assets.Contains(element)).Any())
                    {
                        if (duplicates.Contains(element) == false) { duplicates.Add(element); }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in GroupList)
            {
                item.Assets = item.Assets.Except(duplicates).ToList();
                string result = "";
                foreach (var element in item.Assets)
                {
                    result += element + " ";
                }
                _output.WriteLine($"Name: {item.Name} Asset: {result}");
            }
            Assert.True(duplicates.Count() > 0);
        }
```

output:

```
Name: Group1 Asset: D 
Name: Group2 Asset: E F 
Name: Group3 Asset: H G 
Name: Group4 Asset: I J
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> tempList =  new List<string>();
Dictionary<string, int> keyValuePairs = new Disctionary<string, int>();

GroupList.ForEach(x => {
    tempList.AddRange(x.Assets);
});

tempList.ForEach(X => {
    if(!keyValuePairs.Keys.Contains(x))
    {
        keyValuePairs.Add(x,1);
    }
    else 
    {
        keyValuePairs[x]++;
    }
});

tempList.Clear();

tempList.AddRange(keyValuePairs.Where(x => x.Value > 1).Select(x => x.Key));

GroupList.ForEach(x => {
    var temp = x.Assets;
    x.Assets = temp.Except(tempList).ToList();
});
```