# What is this cast code doing?

Tags: c#, casting

What is this code doing? Specifically the `default(XX)` part. I've never seen it before.

```
Entities.BizTalkRequestResult result = default(Entities.BizTalkRequestResult);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# -Default Keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727346/c-sharp-default-keyword)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a cast; it compiles to the default value of `Entities.BizTalkRequestResult`. For a reference type, e.g., that's probably `null`. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It gives you the default value for the particular type inside the parentheses.  E.g. `0` for primitives numeric types like int or float, or `null` for reference types.  It's useful particularly when the type could vary, and you want to write general code that is applicable for all possible types.

Answer (score 1):

There is a misconception; this is not casting at all. The `default` operator or function returns the default value. ex: 0 for int and null for reference types.
`default` is often used with generics (`default(T)`) because we don't know the actual type at compile time.