# How to set the value of string to null

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am aware that I can set null like

```
string val = null;
```

But I am wondering the other ways I can set it to null. Is there a funcion like `String.null` that I can use.

Comment: Why would you need another way to do it?

Comment: why would doing string val = String.null be any better.. nulls have very little to do with  strings

Comment: You mean a `static void StringUtils.SetNull(out string s)` that sets `s` to `null`? That would be otherkill IMHO. What's wrong with assignment?

Comment: @dash Say I changed it to something and then set it back to null...

Comment: @Ajax3.14 - I'd just set it to `null` as you've done, or even `String.Empty`. Then, if I cared, at least I can check `String.IsNullOrEmpty(val);`

Comment: `string val` in your example is not a string. It's a reference to a string object. You might want to read up on how objects are handled in C#.

Comment: Please note that string.Empty is not the same thing as null. String.Empty is equal to the zero length string "".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you are looking far `String.Empty`

```
string val = String.Empty;
```

**Update:** 
[TheFuzzyGiggler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/883352/thefuzzygiggler) comments are worth mentioning:

> It's much better to set a `string` to `empty` rather than `null`. To avoid
>   exceptions later. If you have to read and write a lot of strings
>   you'll have `null` value exceptions all over the place. Or you'll have a
>   ton of `if(!string.isNullorEmpty(string))` which get annoying

Comment: Beat me to it! If OP reads this.. I've found it's MUCH better to set a string to empty rather than null.. To avoid exceptions later. If you have to read and write a lot of strings you'll have null value exceptions all over the place. Or you'll have a ton of if(!string.isNullorEmpty(string)) which get annoying.

Comment: Thanks for the props. Just glad I can help. I'll let Asif take the rep glory. =)

Comment: Null and String.Empty are certainly not interchangeable. If your system considers them the same, then by all means, use Empty but they are not the same. You can't just willy nilly use one where you can use the other. There is a difference between a user typing in an empty string and a user not typing in anything

Answer (score 16):

You can also use the default keyword.

```
string val = default(string);
```

Here is another SO question regarding the default keyword:
[What is the use of `default` keyword in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727346/c-sharp-default-keyword)

Comment: ...which is the same as `string val = (string)null;`, i.e. a typed null reference.

Comment: @Wormbo - correct. The nice thing about using `default` though, is that it works with both value types and reference types.

Answer (score 4):

`null` is not a special string value (there's `String.Empty` for `""`), but a general object literal for the empty reference.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously one more way to set something to null is to assign result of function that returns null:

```
string SomeFunctionThatReturnsNullString() {return null;}

string val = SomeFunctionThatReturnsNullString();
```

Answer (score 0):

assign it to this value will make it a null ,(chose the right sql datatype , here its double )

```
    System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble.Null
```

Answer (score 0):

I frequently run into this issue when making updates to databases. Especially when the column is a date. If you pass "" or String.Empty, the date is set to MinDate which usually displays as 01/01/1900. So Null is a preferred value when you want No date.

I have had to make sure I capture the "" case and substitute the DBNull.Value which will pass a Null value back to the DB.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DeletedDate)) { 
                db.AddParameter("newDeletedDate", this.DeletedDate);
            }
            else
            {
                db.AddParameter("newDeletedDate", DBNull.Value);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your application you could use `string.Empty`.  I'm always leery of initializing to `null` as the garbage collector is great, but not perfect, and could mark your string for garbage collection if used in some way that the garbage collector can't detect (this is very unlikely though).