# "Constant Expression required" Exception thrown when using Optional Parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, colors, optional-parameters

I get a "Constant Expression required" exception when running this Sub Procedure;

```
Public Sub SolidFill(Optional SolidColor As Color = Color.Black)
    ....
End Sub
```

However, this happens only when using `Color`Types. 
What do I need to do to prevent this exception from being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Public Sub SolidFill(Optional SolidColor As Color = Nothing)
    If SolidColor = Nothing Then SolidColor = Color.Black
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll mark this as an answer. Do you know why this is though? Is there no way to define `SolidFill` with a color in the Parameter brackets?

Comment: better to give credits to Steve, for this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045479/using-color-as-optional-parameter-in-a-function-within-a-class

Comment: @SimonSchödler: The reason you can't use Color.Black as the default value for your optional parameter is that it is not a constant value, Color.Black is a property of the Color Structure that itself returns a Color Structure.