# Rows error help in listview function

Tags: c#, listview

Here is the code I am using.

```
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    ListViewItem lst = default(ListViewItem);
    lst = lvw.Items.Add(row(0));  // My error is on row

    for (int i = 1; i <= data.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        lst.SubItems.Add(row(i));
    }
}
```

Now, what I'm doing or trying to do is actually add database items onto my `listview`. However, I can't seem to get my rows onto my list view. I get a syntax error:

> 'Rows' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'.

I have been struggling with this winform for a couple days and my coding has stopped dead at this point. I have tried changing the parenthesis. Here is the whole function. I got it from the internet in vb.net and ran the code it worked. I then configured that code for my application in vb.net that worked too, now after converting to c# and it doesn't work which is my problem. I went through all the code(I am new to c# like relatively) and fixed most of it to work for my application except the row error

```
private void ShowDataInLvw(DataTable data, ListView lvw)
{       
    lvw.View = View.Details;
    lvw.GridLines = true;
    lvw.Columns.Clear();
    lvw.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
    {
       lvw.Columns.Add(col.ToString());
    }
    foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
    {
        ListViewItem lst = default(ListViewItem);
        lst = lvw.Items.Add(row(0));

        for (int i = 1; i <= data.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            lst.SubItems.Add(row(i));
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, to get to an index of a collection, you need to use `[ ]` (whereas VB uses `( )`). Refer to [this specifically for DataRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z.aspx).

Thus, your code should look like:

```
lst = lvw.Items.Add(row[0]);
```

And

```
lst.SubItems.Add(row[i])
```

On a side note, you may want to read up on the [use of the `default` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727346/what-is-the-use-of-default-keyword-in-c).

**EDIT:**

Here's a complete listing (without spoon-feeding much), after noticing that your code won't *actually* work and assuming you really intend to do as described:

```
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    ListViewItem lst = default(ListViewItem);

    for (int i = 0; i <= data.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
           lst = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());
        else
           lst.SubItems.Add(row[i].ToString());
    }
    lvw.Items.Add(lst);
}
```

Notice a few things:

- The instantiation of `lst` has been changed.
- The `lvw` will add the `lst` along with its subitems.
- The addition will occur only after the subitems have been created.

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested the code, but the idea is there.*

Comment: Good description.  Always in a hurry, so I answer and dash. :)

Comment: I had tried using "[]" and also tried changing the "default" to this code "ListViewItem lst;" which hadn't helped

Comment: The code uses lvw to configure the listview properties have tried changing it to your code while that has removed my errors how will i be able to config the properties without it and will using lst not cause problems if i do so before its actually declared?

Comment: If you really don't get the above working you can always manipulate the incoming datatable, which is most flexible, and then just databind.  Good luck.

Comment: @Broken_Code What do you mean by "able to config the properties without it"? Anyway, the edited code above should work discretely. If your requirement is something else, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: The code does work, I just have some weird error with my database connection. So thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:?

```
lst = lvw.Items.Add(row[0]);

lst.SubItems.Add(row[I]);
```

Comment: And yes i have tried both and it hasn't worked with the change. I actually have a new error message after trying that. Can not changed object to string then an invalid argument error for both.

Comment: What about just binding it:

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ListView ls = new ListView();
        ls.DataSource = dt;
        ls.DataBind();

Comment: lvw.DataSource = data;  lvw.DataBind();

Comment: I have not thought of doing that on account to the fact i would like to manipulate my data after i get the whole thing connected and working properly