# Difference between List and array when initiating

Tags: c#, arrays, list

When I do:

```
List<Person> person = new List<Person>();
person.Print();
```

I do not get anything (null)
However, when I do:

```
Person[] person2 = new person[10];
person2.Print();
```

I get an Exception.
Why? what happens in the memory? I dont get it.

Comment: Show us the `Print` method.

Comment: `new person[10];` should be `new Person[10];`.

Comment: There is no `List<T>.Print` or `Array.Print` method. Where does it come from? Is it an extension method? If so, where is it?

Comment: Most probably an extension method

Comment: but your title is very bad

Comment: where is this Print method? and what error are you getting?

Comment: So there is an extension method `Print` that takes an `IList<Person>` or `IList<T>`? Show it, then we can help to fix it.

Comment: what exception do you get, what is `person`, what is `Print`?

Comment: The base difference between a `List<T>` and an array is that the list doesn't have items until you `Add` them. An array has already allocated the memory and you can access any index in the array, no matter if there is already an item there or not.

Comment: In general, a list or array are collections, their purpose is to store multiple items, in this case persons. If you have an extension that prints them it expects that you pass a collection that contains anything. Your list is empty, so nothing to print. The array's length is 10 but all persons are null references. You have to loop the array and initialize all.

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

```
var people = new Person[10]
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
var people = new List<Person>
   {
       default(Person),
       default(Person),
       default(Person),
       default(Person),
       default(Person),
       default(Person),
       default(Person),
       default(Person),
       default(Person),
       default(Person)
   }
```

now, I suspect your implementation of `Print`, which presumably extends `IList<Person>` doesn't handle `default(Person)`.

---

```
var people = new List<Person>();
```

is actually more equivalent to

```
var people = new Person[0];
```

Does your `Print` implementation work with that?

Comment: The problem is in null references, if Person is a struct it won't throw an exception. BTW, its better explained than mine.

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez, how can you know that, without additional information from the OP?

Comment: A guess... I'm pretty sure that Person is a class and the difference is that the array is initializate with nulls. But a guess.

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez, Its very likely that `default(Person) == null`, its moot though.

Comment: Yes, I didn't say nothing about your `default(Person)`, cause its the correct way, but i think you should update your answer with your `default(Person) == null`

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez, the `default` keyword is not mine, it is part of C#, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727346/what-is-the-use-of-default-keyword-in-c

Comment: I know, i said for clarify it to the OP

Answer (score 1):

## I suggest you to update your method with a null check before doing nothing.

#### You are using them in different way as @Jodrell says in his answer.

With new person[0] you are initializing it with 0 references. But if you use 10, you are creating 10 references to null. The List contains nothing.

I think in your Print method your are doing a loop over the collection and with the List you don't have nothing to loop, but with the array you loop over 10 null references, which causes you Exception.

Comment: So they are different, right?

Comment: Will be the reason, but i hesitate to upvote because OP hasn't shown `Print` method.

Comment: I know, but i'm pretty sure of something like this... I'll wait too to see his code.

Comment: You simply can't know that. Accepting that is the first step. You have an educated guess, nothing more than that.

Comment: Print is exactly that... looping the List vs Looping the Array

Comment: So show the method! @N3wbie

Comment: It's a guess. Built on many similar experience and seeing the different between their initialization I think it should be so close to the real impl.